# Android hardware back button unexpected behavior while using drawer when app coming to foreground from background

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-router-flux

Version
react-native-router-flux 4.0.0-beta.27
react-native 0.51.0

**Expected behaviour**

Let's say i have screen_1 button on drawer and by clicking it I am going to screen_1. Now press the home button(App goes to background) and open the app again(App comes to foreground). Now when i press the android back button the app should go back to drawer screen (drawer in open state) and again pressing the back button should close the drawer.

**Actual behaviour**

I have screen_1 button on drawer and by clicking it I am going to screen_1. Now press the home button(App goes to background) and open the app again(App comes to foreground). Now when i press the android back button the app goes back to home screen (drawer in close state) and again pressing the back button open the screen_1 screen.

This is the code I am using to define scenes.

```
render(){
  return <Router>
      <Scene key="root" headerMode={'screen'}
      >
        <Scene key="drawer" drawer
          contentComponent={SideMenu}
          drawerOpenRoute= 'DrawerOpen'
          drawerCloseRoute= 'DrawerClose'
          drawerToggleRoute= 'DrawerToggle'
          initial={true}
          hideNavBar={true}
          // drawerWidth={400}
        >
          <Scene key="home" component={Home}/>
        </Scene>
        <Scene key="screen_1" component={Screen_1}  />
    </Scene>
  </Router>
}
```

Comment: You might have already looked into this but, why not use BackHandler to do specific actions on hardware back press.

Comment: @NemiShah Already tried that but same thing is happening while using BackHandler as well. Somehow the back event does not get triggered while coming from background on drawer screen.